# Transform JSON into a table and arrange columns in a special manner using jq

Tags: json, jq, export-to-csv

There is JSON like below:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "a": 1,
            "d": 2,
            "c": 3,
            "b": 4
        },
        {
            "a": 5,
            "d": 6,
            "c": 7,
            "b": 8,
            "e": 9
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to transform it to the table like this:

```
c   d   a   b   e
3   2   1   4   <absent>
7   6   5   8   9
```

So:

- Columns `c` and `d` are moved to the beginning of the table;
- All other columns are sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Re "Columns `c` and `d` are moved": This implies you know the names `c` and `d`. How about the other ones? Are they known (i.e. can they be references literally using `a`, `b`, and `d`)? And what about "<absent>"? Is this a literal string?

Comment: I know column names but there are a lot of columns (about 30) and I don't want to list all of them in the filters. "<absent>" is a literal string.

Answer (score 2):

If the key names are known, you could pre-define their order in a variable as an array, then use that for the header as well as the columns in each row. `@tsv` will turn arrays into tab-separated text, so make sure to use `jq -r` or `jq --raw-output`.

```bash
["c","d","a","b","e"] as $keys
| $keys, (.data[] | [.[$keys[]]])
| @tsv
```

```
c   d   a   b   e
3   2   1   4   
7   6   5   8   9
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/XR1jiQ3ymth)

---

If the `<absent>` string was intended to be inserted literally, use `//` to provide an alternative content:

```bash
["c","d","a","b","e"] as $keys
| $keys, (.data[] | [.[$keys[]] | . // "<absent>"])
| @tsv
```

```
c   d   a   b   e
3   2   1   4   <absent>
7   6   5   8   9
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/UYBBiAEfAD_3)

---

> I know column names but there are a lot of columns (about 30) and I don't want to list all of them in the filters.

Then scan the keys first, make a `unique` list, drop `c` and `d`, and prepend them. This is your dynamic `$keys` variable.

```bash
.data
| (map(to_entries[].key | select(IN("c", "d") | not)) | ["c","d"] + unique) as $keys
| $keys, (.[] | [.[$keys[]] | . // "<absent>"])
| @tsv
```

```
c   d   a   b   e
3   2   1   4   <absent>
7   6   5   8   9
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/jsJATziEMhC)

Comment: All that I have right now is `.data | (map(keys_unsorted) | add | unique) as $keys | $keys, map([.[ $keys[] ] | if . == null or . == "" then "<absent>" else . end])[] | @tsv` but don't know how to move certain columns (in my example `c` and `d`) to the beginning.

Comment: I have added how to create the `$key` array dynamically, with `c` and `d` up front.

Comment: I only modified it to `.data | (map(to_entries[].key | select(IN("c", "d") | not)) | ["c", "d"] + unique) as $keys | $keys, (.[] | [.[$keys[]] | if . == null or . == "" then "<absent>" else . end]) | @tsv` because my data can contain empty string as a value and your variant can 'mix' values in the result table.

Answer (score 0):

```
.data
| ["c","d"] as $cd
| ($cd + (add|keys - $cd)) as $keys
| $keys, [.[][$keys[]] // "<absent>"]
| @tsv
```